# Particle picture in the path-integral formulation of Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral

In canonical quantization, the particles arise as quantized excitations on the vacuum $|0\rangle$. For example, a one-particle state with four momentum $p=(E,\textbf{p})$ is given by $$|p\rangle\sim a^\dagger_{p}|0\rangle.$$ Is it possible to arrive at the particle picture in the path-integral formulation of quantum field theory (QFT)? What is the notion of a particle in path-integral way of doing QFT?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Path integrals compute transition amplitudes between quantum states.

#### Disclaimer.

I don't want to go into issues of rigged Hilbert spaces and mathematical correctness of definitions here. This answer gives the general rule of thumb for the path integral formulation.

#### Notation.

In this answer round brackets denote ordinary function arguments (like $\Psi(\vec{x})$), while square brackets denote functional arguments (like $S[\phi(x)]$), which are themselves functions (elements of infinite-dimensional spaces).

#### As a simple toy model, consider quantum mechanics.

Particle state can be described by a wavefunction $\Psi(\vec{x})$. Moreover, transition amplitudes are characterized by initial and final wavefunctions:

$$ \Psi_I(\vec{x}), \Psi_F(\vec{x}) $$

at times $0$ and $\tau$ respectively. The transition amplitude is given by

$$ \left< \Psi_F \right| \hat{U} \left| \Psi_I \right> = \int d^3 x_I \Psi_I (\vec{x}_I) \int d^3 x_F \Psi_F^{*}(\vec{x}_F) \cdot U(\vec{x}_I, \vec{x}_F), $$

where $U(\vec{x}_I, \vec{x}_F)$ are the matrix elements of the evolution operator. These are given by path integrals:

$$ U(\vec{x}_I, \vec{x}_F) = \intop_{\vec{x}(0)=\vec{x}_I}^{\vec{x}(\tau)=\vec{x}_F} {\cal D}x(t) \, e^{i S[\vec{x}(t)]}. $$

The boundary conditions are essential, because they determine the matrix element that is to be evaluated.

#### Generalization to QFT.

In QFT, states live on the infinite-past and infinite-future hyperplanes. We can loosely associate functionals of form

$$ \Psi_I[\phi(\vec{x})], \Psi_F[\phi(\vec{x})] $$

to them. Note that $\Psi$ depends on values of the field at the (initial and final) 3d hyperplanes.

The transition amplitude is given by the path integral

$$ \left< \Psi_F \right| \hat{U} \left| \Psi_I \right> = \int {\cal D}\phi_I \Psi_I[\phi_I] \int {\cal D}\phi_F \Psi_F^{*}[\phi_F] \cdot U[\phi_I(\vec{x}), \phi_F(\vec{x})], $$
$$ U[\phi_I(\vec{x}), \phi_F(\vec{x})] = \intop_{\phi(t_I, \vec{x}) = \phi_I(\vec{x})}^{\phi(t_F, \vec{x}) = \phi_F(\vec{x})} {\cal D}\phi e^{i S[\phi]}, $$

where the integral $\int {\cal D}\phi$ is over field configurations in between of two boundaries. It depends on the chosen boundary field configurations $\phi_I$ and $\phi_F$, and thus can't be factored out.

#### General rule.

States and Hilbert spaces are associated to boundaries. Path integrals are over the bulk region and compute transition amplitudes for the given pair of boundary states.

#### Transition amplitudes between particle states.

In QFT, it is logical to choose the Fock basis (and to label functionals associated to it with *asymptotic* particle states). Thus, path integrals give transition amplitudes between particle states.

The Fock basis is the same as in canonical quantization. It spans the space of rapidly decreasing functionals $\Psi[\phi(\vec{x})]$, and there are actually expressions for the $\Psi$ functional associated to elements of the Fock space. These are given by Hermitian polynomials times decreasing exponentials, just like for the simple Harmonic oscillator.

#### Conclusion

Path integrals are a tool for computation of quantum dynamics, i.e. transition amplitude between quantum states. They don't replace the canonical formalism of Hilbert spaces and self-adjoint operators. They instead complement it by providing a covariant way of deriving transition amplitudes. You still have to do the Hilbert space quantization, and there will be elementary particles as before.